# Abrir una activity dentro de otra activity

Tags: java, android, activity

¿Cómo puedo crear una activity de opciones dentro de otra como esta? o creo que es un tema, ¿Cuál es?

[image: aqui la imagen]

Comment: Lo mas probable es que sea un [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) y no una actividad

Comment: solo basta con poner en el manifest, en la activity: **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"**

Comment: como comentan es un DialogFragment no una actividad.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Nick además de leer [ask], realiza el [tour] del sitio para que entiendas su funcionamiento. Agrega lo que has investigado o realizado, saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Conozco dos formas de hacerlo: la primera,  si deseas que sea como tal una actividad la que se abra, tienes que crear un estilo cuyo padre sea un dialog alert y aplicarlo a tu actividad en el manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="Activity"
        android:theme="@style/customDialog" />

 <style name="customDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorNegro</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

La segunda opción que me parece mejor es hacerlo mediante un dialogo personalizado. Por ejemplo un dialogo con mensaje y un boton sería así

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

Button button;
TextView textview;


private View view;


public CustomDialog (Context context, Activity activity, String message, String text_button){
    super(context);

    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent_back));
    setContentView(view);

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
   textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    setDataOnWidgets(message,text_button);

}

public void setDataOnWidgets(String message, String text_button){
    textview.setText(message);
    button.setText(text_button);

}



public void setButton(View.OnClickListener listener){
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);

}
```

}

Luego en tu actividad, crea y muestra el dialogo;

```
final CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(
                Activity.this,
                Activity.this,
                message,
                text_button);

        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setButton(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        alert.show();
```